# bash: change the name of a file using a list

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list.dat file in which I have the names of 100 file.txt:

```
file1.ic
file2.ic
file3.ic
...
file100.ic
```

I want to read this file and change inside a program.f90 the name of this file iteratively. I have all the files in the same directory. My bash file is:

```
   #!/bin/bash

  touch list.dat

  input='file.in'
  find . -type f -mtime +15 > list.dat
  for G in $(cat list.dat)
  do
   sed -i "48s/$input/$G/" program.f90        
   input=$G
  done
```

But I receive the following error message:

`sed: expression -e #1, character 14: option of s unknown`.

Could you help me? thanks a lot !

Comment: I suppose your file names in `$input` or `$G` contain 
impermissible characters.

Comment: my file in input is 'file.in' and has only numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `find` by default output the file path instead of just the filename (e.g.: `./file1.ic`).
When bash expands your `sed` command, it results in:

```
sed -i "48s/file.in/./file1.ic/" program.f90
```

..and the *option of s unknown* would be `file1.ic/`

---

I would do that in this way. Feel free to change `:` for any character not founded in any filename output by `find`:

```
input='file.in'
while read -r G; do
    sed -i "48s:$input:$G:" program.f90
    input=$G
done < <(find . -type f -mtime +15)
```